# Use the while loop and try-except together

Tags: python, loops

this is my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        varA = int(input('enter your number'))
        varB = int(input('enter your second number'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('ValueError')
```

When varB does not run in terms of ValueError, the loop continues. Okay, but I do not want varA to run. (I want varA to run if the varB value does not give an error.)

Comment: Put separate loops around the input of each variable.

Comment: `try-except` is *not a loop*

Comment: How do you expect Python to know whether ``varB`` *will* succeed while it's only just running the code for ``varA``? Why is that even relevant – the loop is not exited until both succeed. More importantly though, why the restriction on ``varA``-only-if-``varB``-succeeds-after-it – why not just take *both* numbers at once?

Comment: Will start again from varA. If try -except is not in the loop, execution will stop if there is an error

Comment: What does it mean for a variable to "run"?

Comment: That is to receive value. I got my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use 2 loops.

```py
while True:
    try:
        var_a = int(input("enter your number"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")

while True:
    try:
        var_b = int(input("enter your second number"))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
```

Meaning that you keep asking your first number until it does not produce any error. When no error occurs on your first variable, do the same with your second one.